# jquery 'keypress' event not detecting pressing the 'delete' key

Tags: javascript, jquery, key

For some reason when I try to detect if the delete key is pressed. It doesn't work but it does detect other keys being pressed does anybody know why this is happening?
code:

```
$('p:last-child').bind(
    'keypress',
    (data = (e) => {
          console.log(e.keyCode)
          if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            console.log("delete key presssed")
          } 
    }))
```

Comment: @Berto99 Thanks. That worked!

Comment: well, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are attaching an event to `p:last-child`, try to attach it to `input`.

Or if you just want to capture `delete keypress` you need to attach event to the document, like this:

```
$(document).on('keypress', e => console.log(e.keyCode));
```

Comment: I setup my paragraph to be content editable